# Regex - unreachable statement

Tags: java, regex

I have to validate a EUI48 address, currently i am doing it using a for each loop. I would like to do this using regex. But no luck so far.

```
if(!input.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}+"));
            throw new SequenceException("IEEE/EUI48 does not contain a valid HEX value: " + input);

        setSubstitute(inputArgsMap.get(SUBSTITUTE_ID), input);
```

i get a warring on `setSubstitute(inputArgsMap.get(SUBSTITUTE_ID), input);` saying "unreachable statement".

input is a string.

Anyone know what i am doing wrong? :)

Comment: SO, get ready.. there will be at least 10 answers telling exactly the same thing.

Comment: But not enough patience to check ones code minutely in an IDE!

Comment: Get used to _always_ have braces around blocks, then this error cannot happen. You can do that automatically using formatters and save actions in almost any good IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon after the if statement and use braces to surround the body of the conditional block.  Currently, the conditional statement is executed, however its result has no bearing on whether the exception is thrown.  In fact the exception is always thrown, causing the call to `setSubstitute()` to be unreachable.

```
if(!input.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}+")){
    throw new SequenceException("IEEE/EUI48 does not contain a valid HEX value: " + input);
}

setSubstitute(inputArgsMap.get(SUBSTITUTE_ID), input);
```

Comment: i am embarrassed now... However many thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `;` after your `if` statement, so the `throw` statement will always be executed, not just if the input does not match.

It should be

```
if (!input.matches(...)) {
  throw new SequenceException(...);
}

setSubstitute(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to remove semicolon at the end of "if" statement:

```
if(!input.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}+")) {
        throw new SequenceException("IEEE/EUI48 does not contain a valid HEX value: " + input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the semicolon after your if statement; it's equivalent to specifying an empty block, like this:

```
if(!input.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}+")) {
    /* Nothing */
}
throw new SequenceException("IEEE/EUI48 does not contain a valid HEX value: " + input);
setSubstitute(inputArgsMap.get(SUBSTITUTE_ID), input);
```

So your code always raises the exception and the call to `setSubstitute` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement shouldn't have a ; at the end